# Manipulate incorrectly evaluating eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I'm working with a system of differential equations. In this system there are 7 coefficients that I want to simulate numerically to find the eigenvalues at possible coefficients values.

First I created functions for each step:

```
eqs[δ_, σ_, β_, γ_, α_, η_, ρ_] :=
  {-β (A + P) S - γ Y S,
   β (A + P) S + γ Y S - α H,
   α H - η P,
   ρ η P - δ A,
   (1 - ρ) η P - σ Y,
   δ A + σ Y};
sing[δ_, σ_, β_, γ_, α_, η_, ρ_] := 
  Solve[eqs[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ] == 0, {S, H, P, A, Y, R}];
jacob[δ_, σ_, β_, γ_, α_, η_, ρ_] := {
   Grad[eqs[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ], {S, H, P, A, Y, R}] /. 
    sing[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[1]],
   Grad[eqs[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ], 
     {S, H, P, A, Y, R}] /. 
    sing[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]]};
caracpoli[δ_, σ_, β_, γ_, α_, η_, ρ_] := {
   Collect[
    CharacteristicPolynomial[
     jacob[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[1]], λ], λ],
   Collect[
    CharacteristicPolynomial[
     jacob[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]], λ], λ]};
autovalores[δ_, σ_, β_, γ_, α_, η_, ρ_] := {
   Solve[
    caracpoli[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[1]] == 0, λ],
   Solve[
    caracpoli[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]] == 0, λ]};
```

My system has two singularities. The second one has very straightforward eigenvalues:

```
autovalores[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]]
(* {{λ -> 0}, {λ -> 0}, {λ -> -α}, {λ -> -δ}, {λ -> -η}, {λ -> -σ}} *)
```

But the first singularities has some complicated eigenvalues (whose values are stored at the following)

```
autovalores[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]]
```

I want to create a `Manipulate` (with all the seven coefficients of the system) to see the actual value for the eigenvalue. First, I tried to do this for the second singularity, since I already know its eigenvalues, so I can compare to see if my numerical values make sense. I wrote the following:

```
Manipulate[
 autovalores[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]],
 {{β, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{γ, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{α, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{η, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{ρ, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{δ, 0.5}, 0.001, 1},
 {{σ, 0.5}, 0.001, 1}
 ]
```

The problem is that it is now calculating correctly. For example, the third eigenvalue is

```
autovalores[δ, σ, β, γ, α, η, ρ][[2]][[3]][[1]]
(* λ -> -α *)
```

but when I manipulate the `α` value, the eigenvalue is not following the manipulate.

What could be wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure that you didn't have some lingering definitions? Try ```ClearAll["Global`*"]``` before your code. Careful though! You will lose any stored results you have in your current session, so save them if you need them!

Comment: Your code generates error messages for me with "13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)".  The message, `Solve::ratnz`, occurs in `sing` and propagates forward.  Try `sing @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 7]`.